# Choosing best Django architecture for scalability / performance

Tags: django, architecture, model, django-orm

I had a doubt on how to architecture the model.

I want to give some entities the possibility to be voted, in this case, a paper. I came up with this two possibilities:

Option 1:

```
Link the entity as a relationship

class Vote(model.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)

    created = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    value = models.IntegerField(default=1)


class Paper(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    edition = models.ForeignKey(ConferenceEdition)

    votes = models.OneToMany(Vote)
```

advantages:

- It's easier to work with the model (ORM)
- I can use this vote entity with others
- I may need this information when rendering the HTML, to show which papers the user has already voted.

Desavantages:

- I'm afraid the largest the database, the slower it can get.

Option 2:

Not to link the class

```
class Vote(model.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)

    created = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    value = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    entity_id = models.IntegerField()
    entity_type = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='Paper')


class Paper(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    edition = models.ForeignKey(ConferenceEdition)

    num_votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Avantages:

- It's kind of a lazy loading, I have a counter and if I need the information I can go for it.
- It's faster ( I think )

Desavantages:

- You must rely on a new logic to update all the new votes.

Option 3:

I'm listening

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django loads many to many fields only if you explicitly call them.

So in your 1st case:

```
paper.votes.all()
```

If you want to load all the votes when doing your query, you can in django 1.4 do [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

```
paper = Paper.objects.get(pk=1).prefetch_related('votes')
```

By the way, instead of .all() you can use .count(), which generates a different database query that is much faster since it only has to count values, instead of retrieve them into django/python.

There is also a third approach:

You coud have extra field in your model: votes_count, that you would update on pre_save(), and it would hold that value for you. This way you get both: you can query for all votes, but you can also just grab a number.

Comment: +1 You should definitely consider combination of the 1st and 3rd approach. Just one thing I'm not sure about is having `votes` ManyToManyField as I'm not sure the same vote is applicable to multiple papers. If that's not the case OneToMany will suffice.

Comment: Yes sorry for that, I meant oneToMany. My Fault, I will edit the question.